# UFT/QTP=Is it possible to get 'Transaction' time from result viewer?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am using 'Transaction' feature to find out exact loading time. I am getting transaction time in 'Result Viewer'. Is it possible to get that transaction time in excel or is it possible to store transaction time in variable?

Please find attached screen shot for more details

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Any reason not to just set a variable (`startTime = Now()`) before you call the first step, then once it's done, perform a `datediff` between the current time and the previously recorded `startTime`? Then you can do whatever you like with the duration, store it in a variable, write it to a datatable etc

Comment: Thanks Dave....  
I got one more solution. We can use
StartTime=Timer
EndTime=Timer

ExecutionTime=EndTime-StartTime

Answer (score 1):

Use the following functions, call these at appropriate places. If you only want to use it once then simply remove the function syntax.

```
  Function StartTimer
  iTimerStart = Timer()
  End Function 

 Function StopTimer
 iTimerStop = Timer()
 DataTable("TimeTaken", dtLocalSheet) = iTimerStop - iTimerStart
 End Function
```